# Running a Daemon remotely and in the background of Desktop Application

Tags: c#, linux, ssh, ssh.net

I want to make a GUI that starts and stops a script that's on a remote Linux server. I have successfully SSH'd into the remote server using SSH.NET and can successfully run the script. However, the whole program then comes to a stand still because the remote script hasn't completed. (This script should not complete and is in fact monitoring behavior). I want to be able to stop the script by pressing a button that will execute a stop command to that script process. I figured I may need to set up multiple threads on the Desktop app for this to happen as well as the Linux server by using the '&' command.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Code Below:

```
private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         isPBXMonitoringEnabled = true;

         using (SshClient ssh = new SshClient("server", "uname", "pw"))
         {
             ssh.Connect();

             var cmd = ssh.CreateCommand("./phpScripts/script.php");


             var asynch = cmd.BeginExecute();

             var reader = new StreamReader(cmd.OutputStream);

             while (!asynch.IsCompleted) ///This wont complete... I need to find a way to allow this to go on but take in a command to stop it when i need to.
             {
                 var result = reader.ReadLine();
                 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                     continue;
                 Console.Write(result);
             }
             cmd.EndExecute(asynch);


             ssh.Disconnect();
         }



     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you know the answer.  Once the application has started the remote process, you need another thread to do the sending of the quit command.